# why the top not align properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make a simple row demo in which i take card from ionic framework.Actually my first card is not vertically align with second card why ?
my first card is some margin below to second card .But third card is same horizontal plan with fourth 
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbWqJE[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
  <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">     
    <ion-content>     
        <div class="row">     
            <div class="col">     
                <div class="card">     
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">      This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping
                        text.     
                    </div>
                         
                </div>
                     
            </div>
                 
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">     
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">      This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping
                        text.     
                    </div>
                         
                </div>
            </div>
                      
        </div>
             
        <div class="row">     
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">     
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">      This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping
                        text.     
                    </div>
                         
                </div>
            </div>
                 
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">     
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">      This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping
                        text.     
                    </div>
                         
                </div>
            </div>
                      
        </div>

    </ion-content>

</ion-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the first column in the first row, you have some whitespaces after `<div class="col">`. Simply removing those will fix it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaPMYE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok **'white dots'** seemed strange in html part from first look, and i looked in deeper. This dots represent `\u2028` code as 'line separator' also known as `\n`. And Your template built view with them. I deleted one of them `div class="col"` from first card and all stand as it should be.

[Your Fork](http://codepen.io/icrosil/pen/WQrxNb)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/avdZoL)**

```
 <div class="row row-center">    
  ...
</div>
```

You can use like this for vertical alignment on the columns as well:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x190"></div>
  <div class="col col-top">Caption Top</div>
  <div class="col col-bottom">Caption bottom</div>
</div>
```

**FOR REFERENCE:** **[Link](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/using-the-grid/)**